# How do I list all versions of a gem available at a remote site?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version

I'm trying to find out all the remotely available versions of a specified gem.

I tried using:

```
gem list rhc --remote
```

But it shows:

```
*** REMOTE GEMS ***
rhc (0.84.15)
rhcp (0.2.18)
rhcp_shell (0.2.12)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Well, it was easier than I thought (well, not really, let's say as easy as it should be):

```
gem list rhc --remote --all
```

Which returns:

```
*** REMOTE GEMS ***
rhc (0.84.15, 0.84.13, 0.83.9, 0.82.18, 0.81.14, 0.80.5, 0.79.5, 0.77.8, 0.75.9, 0.74.6, 0.74.5, 0.73.14, 0.72.29, 0.71.2, 0.69.6, 0.69.3, 0.68.5)
rhcp (0.2.18, 0.2.17, 0.2.16, 0.2.15, 0.2.14, 0.1.9, 0.1.8, 0.1.7, 0.1.6, 0.1.5, 0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2)
rhcp_shell (0.2.12, 0.2.11, 0.0.9, 0.0.7, 0.0.6, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1)
```

Comment: Also note that "rhc" is a regex, so if you only want to look at that one, you could search for `gem list ^rhc$` and the "--remote" and "--all" flags can be abbreviated and combined for `gem list ^rhc$ -ra`

Comment: note that you can pass other options, ie. to get latest pre-releases of phusion passenger you'd want to: `gem list -ra --pre passenger` (-ra == --remote --all)

Comment: @JoshuaCheek note that some shells like `zsh` have more advanced parsing and could catch the regex given in this way. To be more safe (if putting sth like that in a script or README) is to put it in a string so that we're sure we pass it 1-1, i.e. `gem list '^rhc$'` etc.

Comment: @m_gol happened to be reading down the comments as my `zsh` did this +1 for your help!

Comment: use `--prerelease` to see beta versions

Answer (score 41):

According to [RubyGem's Guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#finding-gems) you should use the `search` keyword. So the command could be:

`gem search rhc --all`

If you want the exact name use:

`gem search ^rhc$ --all`

If you want to include prerelease versions use `--pre`

`gem search ^rhc$ --pre`

And if you're using `zsh` add quotes:

`gem search '^rhc$' --all`

Comment: use `--prerelease` to see beta versions

Answer (score 10):

To extend @eyalev's answer, if you want a list of one version per line, here's a one-liner:

```
gem search '^rspec$' --all \
  | grep -o '\((.*)\)$' \
  | tr -d '() ' \
  | tr ',' "\n" \ 
  | sort
0.0.10
0.1.0
0.1.1
# etc.
```

To make this a bit more re-usable, you could write some functions (pardon my limited bash skills):

```
function extract_gem_versions() {   
  echo "$1" \
    | grep -o '\((.*)\)$' \
    | tr -d '() ' \
    | tr ',' "\n"; 
}

function gem_versions() { 
  local gem_name="$1"; 
  local pattern="^${gem_name}$";  
  local vers_str="$(gem search ${pattern} --all)";  
  extract_gem_versions "$vers_str";  
}

gem_versions rspec | sort
0.0.10
0.1.0
0.1.1
# etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

[`gem info`](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-info) offers both a `--remote` option to only check remote gems and `--all` to display all known versions:

```bash
$ gem info rhc --remote --all

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

rhc (1.38.7, 1.38.4, 1.37.1, 1.36.4, 1.35.4, 1.35.3, 1.35.1, 1.34.2, 1.33.4, 1.32.2, 1.31.5, 1.30.3, 1.30.2, 1.29.7, 1.28.5, 1.27.4, 1.26.9, 1.25.3, 1.25.2, 1.24.4, 1.23.7, 1.22.5, 1.21.3, 1.20.3, 1.19.5, 1.18.2, 1.17.6, 1.16.9, 1.15.6, 1.14.7, 1.13.6, 1.12.4, 1.11.4, 1.10.7, 1.9.6, 1.8.9, 1.7.8, 1.6.8, 1.5.13, 1.4.8, 1.4.7, 1.3.8, 1.2.7, 1.1.11, 1.0.4, 0.98.16, 0.97.17, 0.96.9, 0.95.14, 0.95.13, 0.94.8, 0.93.19, 0.93.18, 0.92.11, 0.91.12, 0.91.11, 0.90.7, 0.90.6, 0.88.9, 0.87.8, 0.86.7, 0.85.12, 0.84.15, 0.84.13, 0.83.9, 0.82.18, 0.81.14, 0.80.5, 0.79.5, 0.77.8, 0.75.9, 0.74.6, 0.74.5, 0.73.14, 0.72.29, 0.71.2, 0.69.6, 0.69.3, 0.68.5)
    Author: Red Hat
    Homepage: https://github.com/openshift/rhc

    OpenShift Client Tools
```

`gem (list|search)` offer similar (`--remote --all`) but if you're looking for a specific gem the `--exact` option only looks for exact matches:

```bash
$ gem search rhc --remote --all --exact

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

rhc (1.38.7, 1.38.4, 1.37.1, 1.36.4, 1.35.4, 1.35.3, 1.35.1, 1.34.2, 1.33.4, 1.32.2, 1.31.5, 1.30.3, 1.30.2, 1.29.7, 1.28.5, 1.27.4, 1.26.9, 1.25.3, 1.25.2, 1.24.4, 1.23.7, 1.22.5, 1.21.3, 1.20.3, 1.19.5, 1.18.2, 1.17.6, 1.16.9, 1.15.6, 1.14.7, 1.13.6, 1.12.4, 1.11.4, 1.10.7, 1.9.6, 1.8.9, 1.7.8, 1.6.8, 1.5.13, 1.4.8, 1.4.7, 1.3.8, 1.2.7, 1.1.11, 1.0.4, 0.98.16, 0.97.17, 0.96.9, 0.95.14, 0.95.13, 0.94.8, 0.93.19, 0.93.18, 0.92.11, 0.91.12, 0.91.11, 0.90.7, 0.90.6, 0.88.9, 0.87.8, 0.86.7, 0.85.12, 0.84.15, 0.84.13, 0.83.9, 0.82.18, 0.81.14, 0.80.5, 0.79.5, 0.77.8, 0.75.9, 0.74.6, 0.74.5, 0.73.14, 0.72.29, 0.71.2, 0.69.6, 0.69.3, 0.68.5)
```

`gem info` will return at most one gem; `gem (list|search)` might return multiple gems. `gem info` seems ideal if you know what you are looking for; `gem (list|search)` might helpful when there's uncertainty of the gem name. Also `gem list` describes itself for search local gems despite it being capable of remote operations.

It doesn't look like there's a command/set of options that returns only the available remote versions for a gem. To riff on the answer [@jared-beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567762/jared-beck) gave, one could extract that with text manipulation:

```bash
$ gem info rhc --remote --all | grep -o '\((.*)\)$' | tr -d '() ' | tr ',' "\n"
1.38.7
1.38.4
1.37.1
1.36.4
1.35.4
# ... truncated ...
```

Answer (score 1):

## Better Solution

```sh
gem search '^rhc$' --all
```

### Motivation to this shared knowledge

I see an accepted answer that throw unexpected results

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
gem list [STRING] [options]
```

For example:

```
gem list rhc -r
```

Or try:

```
gem list -r rhc
```

(*the documentation, and the example provided seem to contradict each other - try both*)

---

See the documentation:

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page34

Comment: This does not list all versions