# How do I find the lastest version of a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How can I see the latest available version of a gem using the Linux command line interface?

Using gem, the closest I can get is `gem list -d [gemname]`, which appears to list only the latest version installed. I'm not sure if there are other CLI programs that can help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146012/ruby-list-all-versions-of-a-gem-available-at-remote-site

may also help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gem list rails -ra` means:

"show me all the rails versions available for installation"

```
Usage: gem list [STRING] [options]
[...]
    -a, --all                        Display all gem versions
    -r, --remote                     Restrict operations to the REMOTE domain
```

The resulting response can be quite long for gems that have had a number of revisions.

Answer (score 3):

This way:

```
gem list your_gem_name -r
```

Comment: This shows all packages with names that contain the searched string, which may include plugins. To search for exact matches, use a regex, as in `gem list '^your_gem_name$' -r`.