# What is the best and quickest process for adding a gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Is there a way to automatically add a gem and its current version to my Gemfile?  The closest thing I've found is the gem 'Gemrat' here:

https://github.com/DruRly/gemrat

It doesn't seem to be actively supported so I thought perhaps someone has discovered a better process / tool.  It just seems like an extra step at times to hunt down the latest version of a well known gem when I know I just want to use the latest version (but lock that version in).

Comment: you could use standard gem commands to find the latest version such as `gem list GEM_NAME --remote` Or add the `--all` tag to see all available versions. you can also use `search` eg. `gem search GEM_NAME`  This way you don't have to "hunt down the latest version". Then enter it into your gem file with the specific version specified. eg. `gem 'gem_name_here', 'version_number_here'` to lock your app to that version. Just found a nice [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146012/how-do-i-list-all-versions-of-a-gem-available-at-a-remote-site) on the subject.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  Discovering the version number is not the issue, I was just hoping to automate the process and was wondering if anyone else had tackled this.

Answer (score 1):

`echo 'gem "nokogiri"' >> Gemfile && bundle install`

Comment: This doesn't include the current version, which is the crux of the issue