# Can I install random, but valid, dependencies of a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm developing a gem, and I'd like to simulate how it will be actually used in the wild. I would like to automate testing it with any satisfactory version of its dependencies.

For example, if my gemspec claims `spec.add_dependency "nokogiri", '~> 1.2'` then I'd want to automate installing anywhere from 1.2.0 to the latest 1.x. Ideally it would do the same for nokogiri's dependencies.

Comment: @engineersmnky Ideally, yes, at every level. But just the shallow dependencies would be a good start. One could [go through the list manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146012/how-do-i-list-all-versions-of-a-gem-available-at-a-remote-site), filter for those which match the version spec (not sure how to get that programmatically), and pick one at random.

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually looking for a way to list every possible dependency of a Gem and every possible dependency of those dependencies, and so on.

The following should technically work

```
def gem_list(gem)
  gem.runtime_dependencies.each_with_object({}) do |dep,obj| 
    # considerations for platform may be required 
    # check the output from the gem list command 
    obj[dep.name] =  `gem list #{dep.name} -r -e -a`.scan(/\d+\.\d+.\d+/)
      .filter_map do |v| 
        if dep.requirement.satisfied_by?(Gem::Version.create(v)) 
          # load spec from the yaml output of the gem specification command
          spec = Gem::Specification.from_yaml(`gem specification #{dep.name} -r -v #{v}`)
           # recursively load the spec dependency chains for each dependent gem
          { v=> gem_list(spec)}
      end  
    end
  end
end 
spec = Gem::Specification.load(PATH_TO_YOUR_GEMSPEC)
dependency_trees = gem_list(spec)
```

[Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/getgemversions#main.rb) using nokogiri.gemspec (which is a fairly short list)

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency("mini_portile2", "~> 2.8.0")
spec.add_runtime_dependency("racc", "~> 1.4")
```

Output

```
{"mini_portile2"=>[{"2.8.0"=>{}}],
 "racc"=>
  [{"1.6.1"=>{}},
   {"1.6.0"=>{}},
   {"1.5.2"=>{}},
   {"1.5.1"=>{}},
   {"1.5.0"=>{}},
   {"1.4.16"=>{}},
   {"1.4.15"=>{}},
   {"1.4.14"=>{}},
   {"1.4.13"=>{}},
   {"1.4.12"=>{}},
   {"1.4.11"=>{}},
   {"1.4.10"=>{}},
   {"1.4.9"=>{}},
   {"1.4.8"=>{}},
   {"1.4.7"=>{}},
   {"1.4.6"=>{}}]}
```

Please note this could go on for a very long time depending on the number of gems that satisfy the requirement and the number of gems that are in the dependency chain.

This will not actually install the gems. So my "recommended" process would be:

1. Build this list
2. Then traverse the deeply nested stacks and flatten each into a dependency chain
3. Install a single dependency chain
4. Test
5. Clear all gems
6. Repeat 3-5 until no chains are left

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start! I cut this down by only checking `gem.runtime_dependencies` and also sampling one version before recursing; I only need one set per test run. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/schwern/1066a5faa9caa91aeb3f91a105f5723b). There's also some caching which can be done for repeated dependencies.

Comment: I suppose I could even produce a Gemfile.lock from this. That would handle the installation step.

Comment: @Schwern yes you could. I have a whole separate answer on Gemfile dependency traversal. Also if you are caching there are a lot of other useful mechanisms in the `Gem` namespace e.g. `Gem::Dependency#to_specs`. This should at least get you moving forward. TBH it was a strange request but a reasonably fun run around as I don't get much occasion to look through the `Gem` docs.

Comment: Yes, this will let me move forward. I might even package it into a gem. :) Why did it strike you as strange? This is my first time developing a gem, is it a realistic thing to test?

Comment: @Schwern that is certainly an atypical thing to test. Generally speaking one would test their code which obviously interacts with the dependencies but you can usually assume that those libraries are tested against their own dependencies so there is no real need to test every combination.

Comment: The intent isn't to test the deps, but the version combinations. For example, am I using a feature that's newer than my minimum version spec? It's an integration test. My gem is unit tested. And all the deps are (hopefully) unit tested. This is testing integrations with different versions.